# MDX query not raising precise error message

Tags: mdx, powerpivot, olap, mdx-query

I am trying to execute the following query on Power Pivot :

`SELECT NON EMPTY {[DimItemsGeneralData].[Item Code].[All], [DimItemsGeneralData].[Item Code].AllMembers} ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY {[DimItemsGeneralData].[Gross Weight].[All], [DimItemsGeneralData].[Gross Weight].AllMembers} ON ROWS FROM [Modèle] WHERE ([DimItemsGeneralData].[Material Type Code].&[ZPF], [DimItemsByPlants].[Plant Status Code].&[04]);`

and it is raising the following error message with no further info : Failure of 'MSOLAP.8' without any error message available, result code: E_FAIL(0x80004005

Is it likely to be linked to the syntax of the query ?

It takes a few minutes before raising the error

Thank you